# Laravel mix.copy and mix.copyDirectory files makes mix-manifest super-large

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I have a problem with Laravel Mix. Every file touched by mix. copy and mix.copyDirectory gets included in the mix-manifest.json. Because I'm copying many images, the mix-manifest weighs over 1 MB. I want the mix-manifest not to have assets like images, so it only includes JS and CSS files. Is this possible? How to do it?